# How would I fix indentation on an font awesome icon?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, indentation

How do I fix the indentation whilst using this font awesome icon as list to display advantages?

This is my HTML:

```
<p> <i class="f_item_tick fa fa-check"></i>
No upfront payment is required to access the solution. A Nominee and Supervisory fee are both payable once the solution is active. These are taken from the monthly contributions you pay into.
</p>
```

I don't have much CSS applied besides the following to make the tick green:

```
.f_item_tick {
    color: #00a885;
    font-size:1.8rem;
}
```

Ideally I want it so the `payable` is in line with `No` (See Image)

[image: Indentation Fix]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to change the markup, the simplest way is to give the `<p>` element `position:relative` and place the icon with `position:absolute` inside the padded-area:

```css
p {
  padding-left: 2em;
  position: relative;
}

p .fa {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<p> 
  <i class="f_item_tick fa fa-check"></i> 
  No upfront payment is required to access the solution. A Nominee and Supervisory fee are both payable once the solution is active. These are taken from the monthly contributions you pay into. 
</p>
```

- Please note the above code is *proof-of-concept* and has selectors that are too general to be used in production environment (it would affect all the `<p>` elements in your project).
  To only apply it to (a) particular element(s) you could add a custom class to the desired `<p>` element(s).

---

Another option is to get the icon outside of its parent and wrap them together in a parent with `display:flex;`

```css
.flex-item {
  display: flex;
}
.flex-item .fa {
  padding: 1em 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  
<div class="flex-item">
  <i class="f_item_tick fa fa-check"></i>
  <p> No upfront payment is required to access the solution. A Nominee and Supervisory fee are both payable once the solution is active. These are taken from the monthly contributions you pay into. </p>
</div>
```

---

Yet another option is to give your `text-indent` a negative value equal to the sum of `margin-left` + `padding-left` properties. You'll need to apply the margin + padding sum to the `<i>` element, too:

```css
p {
  text-indent: -2em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
p .fa {
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<p>
  <i class="fa fa-check"></i>No upfront payment is required to access the solution. A Nominee and Supervisory fee are both payable once the solution is active. These are taken from the monthly contributions you pay into. 
</p>
```

Comment: This worked an absolute charm. Thank you very much

How would I be able to implement this for a standalone `<li>`?

Comment: @Adam, the principle stands: `position:absolute` positions the child relative to the closest parent with `position:relative` (which should be `<li>`, in that case). Give a `padding-left` to the `<li>` to accommodate the icon, because now you're placing it outside the document flow.

Comment: Thank you! That worked a charm and I've also learnt something new (Y)

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the Font Awesome list-item utility classes, .e.g `fa-ul` and `fa-li`

Ref: [Font Awesome Examples - List Icons](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/icons-in-a-list)

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.f_item_tick {
  color: #00a885;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><i class="fa-li f_item_tick fa fa-check fa-fw"></i> No upfront payment is required to access the solution. A Nominee and Supervisory fee are both payable once the solution is active. These are taken from the monthly contributions you pay into. </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need this css:

```html
.f_item_tick {
            color: #00a885;
            font-size:1.8rem;
            display: block;
            float: left;
        }
```

You could also add `padding-right: 10px;` to that.

Comment: So, essentially, you just add those 2 or 3 lines to the class you already have.

Comment: Note that my solution is elegant because it doesn't require you to change anything in your HTML and doesn't require any additional css classes. You merely just add 2 or 3 lines to your existing css class and that's it.